# Applying to grad school - Need to indicate history in previous not so good school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application

I'm applying for grad school. The application asks to list out all schools attended previously.

However, long time ago I attended a not so good school and I even felt the degree was not accredited, so I quit (with graded transcript). Later on, I completed my undergrad in another school.

Do you think I should indicate this bad school in my application? If I do need to indicate, what I'm afraid is that it would be hard for my future grad school to verify my status in this bad school. I'm not afraid of grade or whatever, but just feel like it's not worth it to be indicated. If I don't, would there be any issue later on?

Answer (score 2):

You should disclose any previous schools when asked.

If you didn't like your previous school, that may or may not be a topic for the interview. However, if you choose to hide this information, consider the following:

1. did you transfer credits from your "bad" school to the "good" one? The admissions will probably ask where the missing courses are.
2. did you start in your "good" school from scratch? The admissions will probably ask what you were doing in the meantime.

Either leads down a rather uncomfortable conversation path.

On the other hand, if you are honest from the start, I imagine that the admission persons don't even care that much and won't mention it.

Bottom line, it is never a good idea to hide facts when applying anywhere.

Comment: Agreed. Never lie in an application letter. Otherwise, the grad school you are applying to is very unlikely to care about your previous attendance at a degree mill; I do not see how it is relevant to your work going forward.